# SwiftUI: How to display UserDefault data in different views

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

Currently, I have a bool "heart" button for users to tap on and saved the changed value to UserDefault Database

```
struct RootView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.userSettings.isVisited.toggle() }) {
            if self.userSettings.isVisited {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill").font(.title)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart").font(.title)
            }
        }.foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Now, I want to display "heart" changed value in another view. How would I achieve it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If your `UserSettings` stores/observers settings directly in/with `UserDefaults`, then in another view you can just use another, own, instance of `UserSettings`

For example:

```
struct AnotherView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.userSettings.isVisited {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill").font(.title)
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "heart").font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you should store single instance of `UserSettings` somewhere at top level (Scene, Application, etc.) and inject that single instance in both (all) views as environment object

```
struct RootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings

...

struct AnotherView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userSettings: UserSettings
...
```